# Can the output Key type from a Mapper be changed before it enters Reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

If the mapper is emitting a set of key value pairs, can we do some processing in the sort and shuffle method and change the key type so that the reducer accepts a key type which is of a different kind?

Comment: Can you explain your use case as to why you can't just change the output type of the mapper (why this has to be done in the shuffle stage?)

Comment: As @Chris White says you can change the types, not even if you're using a combiner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it with a combiner?  Design it as a pass-thru for the actual data except you just modify the data type.  It is a stranger requirement.  Are you re-purposing old code?

Comment: I don't think it's safe to rely on solely the combiner to change the key type. If I remember correctly, the combiner is not always guaranteed to run.

Comment: There are other functions you can run it through such as what you would do with a secondary sort.  Perhaps you can do the conversion through that?

Comment: I feel like it would be better to just output whatever keytype you want within the mapper haha

Comment: Not sure, if this approach really works. The O/P KV types of the Map should match with the I/P KV types of the Reduce function and the Combiner should have the same I/P and O/P KV types. Can you please provide an example with the I/O KV types for the Map, Reducer and the Combiner functions?